# Ping devices in sleep mode?

Tags: linux, bash, ping, sleep-mode

On my Linux machine I wrote a bash code that periodically pings some devices, including some android one. The problem is that some of these devices result to be not pingable (although they are connected to the wifi) due to the sleep-mode policy.

I've try `arping` instead of `ping` and that seems to be able to ping the devices in sleepmode.
However in my bash script I haven't been able to use the `arping` command as a boolean if condition, indispensable to replace the `ping` command.

From:

`if ping -c 1 ${ip[$i]} &> /dev/null
then [...]`

To:

`if arping     ...?     &> /dev/null
then [...]`

I need a single ping that return `true`if `arping` gets a response, `false` if it times out (or, if you have other better solutions, I'll take any suggestions!).

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: It works for me as is. You're sure it's not working? (if arping -c 1 ${mac} >&/dev/null then; ... fi)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you're almost right, I had not tried to use the same command.

Almost because `arping` want a `sudo` call and which connection it should scan:

```
if sudo arping -i wlan0 -c 1 ${ip[$i]} &> /dev/null
then [...]
```

Thanks for your time! :)